# R: What is the most efficient way to select certain rows in a dataframe

Tags: r

Out of the dataframe `Question`, with columns `Question$Temperature`, `Question$Salary`, I want to select only the `Salary`'s with `Temperature` higher than 10. I always do the following:

```
Question[Question$Temperature>10]$Salary
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: Your example code is invalid for selecting rows. Did you mean `Question[Question$Temperature>10, ]$Salary`?

Answer (score 1):

It's more efficient to use

```
Question$Salary[Question$Temperature > 10]
```

since you do not subset a whole data frame but the values of a vector,

Answer (score 1):

three common ways with benchmarking

```
l<-data.frame(x=sample(1:10,1000, replace=T), y=runif(1000))
f1<-function(df){l2=df[df$x>8,"y"]}
f2<-function(df){l2=df[df$x>8,]$y}
f3<-function(df){l2=df$y[df$x>8]}
print(microbenchmark(f1(l), f2(l), f3(l), times=1000))
```

result

```
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min      lq  median      uq      max neval
 f1(l)  97.428 101.378 102.696 107.962 3757.555  1000
 f2(l) 247.081 253.226 257.614 270.780  734.659  1000
 f3(l)  59.686  62.319  63.197  64.514 3793.980  1000
```